# Div is not calculating height automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div which contains 2 elements. First element is a `span` and second element is an 
`input`, like:

```
<div id="container">
   <span>FirstName</span>
   <br />
   <input type="text" />
</div>
```

The `width` of `container` div is set to `300px` and I was expecting that it will automatically calculate its `height` according to its children's height. Here it calculates its height, but it didn't include the `input` element height.

What's going on here?

**EDIT**

My container `position : absolute` and because of some reason i can't set `overflow : hidden`

Comment: Is the `</div` not closed in your actual code?

Comment: Try adding `overflow: hidden` style to `#container`. I think you have given css float which is the reason your div is not expanding vertically.

Comment: Can you provide a test case? Are you floating the span and the input? If so, try adding #container {overflow: hidden;} in your CSS file.

Comment: The comment written that div is not closed is enough. I tried editing his post but not able to as it is a small edit. So i thought this will help him. As he has 583 reputation point i dont think he will forget to close a div.

Comment: Please post the CSS you are for these elements

Comment: Just with the information you've given us, that doesn't seem to be the case: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/dccF2/

Comment: Well, even with `position: absolute` I can't recreate: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/dccF2/1/

Comment: It's a guess because the information given (by the OP) doesn't prove the result described: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/dccF2/1/

Comment: Its working fine even with position absolute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working demo with jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/dccF2/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use `height:inherit;` in the child elements.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following -

```
#container{
width:300px;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
}​
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UyJgV/1/)

EDIT: added `Position:absoulte`

Updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UyJgV/3/)

Comment: `height` by default _is_ `auto`

Comment: The problem is you didn't have the described issue before you solved it: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/UyJgV/2/

Comment: @VivekChandra you posted answer only by guessing that it could be an issue without understanding where the OP was using floats for inner elements or not

Comment: @ jared - the OP updated his question.. @Dipaks - the OP dint paste any CSS.. hence,i too dint include it anywhere..