# div doesn't automatically size to contents

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Why doesn't the blue div automatically expand to the height of the
input field?

[link to jsfiddle](http://bit.ly/1K90rM3)

Is that some css rule I don't know about?  Is it a Jquery or Jquery Mobile thing?

Comment: can you edit your code to be the minimum needed to show the issue, and what steps have you tried?

Comment: try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113601/div-is-not-calculating-height-automatically - there are many others about <div> heights, I presume you know you set the height to 20px

Comment: yeah i saw the height was set to 20px.  I need it otherwise the div is unseen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the generated code, you'll see that jQuery mobile has added in an extra div around your input element:

```
 <div style="height:20px; width: 90%;background-color:blue">
    <div class="ui-input-search ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-mini ui-shadow-inset ui-input-has-clear">
        <input type="text" data-type="search" name="search" value="" data-mini="true">
        <a href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"
           class="ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-input-clear-hidden"
           title="Clear text">Clear text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to get rid of it, add `data-role="none"` to your input element.

Or, if you want to keep the jQuery mobile styles and just fix the blue box, you can add in a clear fix div. This is required because the jQuery Mobile style is setting an absolute position and thereby taking the input element out of the page flow so its height is not used to size the surrounding div. You can fix like this (also remember to take the height:20px; off your div)

```
 <div style="width: 90%;background-color:blue">  
              <input type="search" name="search" value="" data-mini="true" data-theme="c" />
     <div style="clear: both;"></div></div>
```

Comment: if i do that then i lose the jQuery mobile niceties like turning this input field into a search bar.  are those my only options - transform it into a normal input field or deal with the div weirdness?

Comment: I've updated my answer with another suggestion for fixing your issue.